# ShowDialog() in vb.net not working properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure if this question has been already posted or not but since I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for so I'll ask anyways.

When I use ShowDialog() to call another form from the current form it just displays the name of the controls the first time it opens, if I close it and open it again then it displays at it should have. For example if I write a simple code as follows

Form1

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Display("Message")
End Sub
End Class
```

Form2

```
Public Class Form2
Public Sub Display(ByVal msg As String)
    Me.ShowDialog(Parent)
    Label1.Text = msg
End Sub
End Class
```

When I click the button the first time all I get is "Label1" instead of "Message" displayed on the called form but when I click on the button a second time I get the desired output. 
I tried the same thing with Show() and didn't have any such problem. But I need the called form to be modal (like a MessageBox), so is there any other way to do it or can someone tell me the right way to use ShowDialog() ?
I'm new to vb so please keep it simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShowDialog is a blocking call. You need to set everything before you call it.